# prevent delete from collection privilege

Tags: mongodb, authorization, roles, mongodb-roles

I want to allow certain users to update and insert, but not to delete. I have created the following role

```
    db.createRole({
    role: "readWriteNoDelete",
    privileges: [{
        resource: {
            db: "permitmanager",
            collection: ""
        },
        actions: ["insert", "update"]
    }],
    roles: [{
        role: "read",
        db: "permitmanager"
    }]
})
```

I assigned it to my current user, confirmed by running this:

```
> db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})
{
"authInfo" : {
    "authenticatedUsers" : [
        {
            "user" : "defaultuser",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "permitmanager"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWriteNoDelete",
            "db" : "permitmanager"
        }
    ]
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

However, I am still able to delete from a collection within permitmanager:

```
> db
permitmanager
> db.leads.remove({"estDollarAmount": 0})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
```

What am I missing? I would think that if the 'remove' action wasn't present on their privileges they would not be able to do this

Answer (score 0):

Turns out authentication wasn't enabled on the database, (add --auth to the mongod startup command)